# How to change icon and gravity of Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

this is my toolbar

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:gravity="end"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

i am try with

```
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:gravity="end"
```

for change the toolbar position to right but is still same

[image]

also when i try change the toolbar icon its add new one behind it !

this code i use it for change icon

```
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home);
```

and result

[image]

the style i use it in toolbar

```
 <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: Just add an `ImageButton` to your `Toolbar`, and set an `OnClickListener` on it to handle the drawer opening/closing.

Comment: @MikeM. and how to hide the default icon ?

Comment: Which icon do you mean?

Comment: @MikeM. see first icon on the left

Comment: Get rid of the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, and remove the `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled()` call.

Comment: @MikeM. i cannot find setDisplayShowHomeEnabled on my code

Comment: I meant the `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);` call, from the code you posted above.

Comment: i remove it dosent change any thing i disable setSupportActionBar(mToolbar); also and only the title removed

Comment: Well, that leftmost icon is normally a result of an `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. If you removed that and it still shows, then you've got something else creating it. Figure out what it is, and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Create topbar with custom view, put an icon in end side, put your drawer on the end too, then manage onClick in that icon

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

findViewById(R.id.iconEnd).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END))
              drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
            else
              drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        }
});
```

I hope this help

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
remove only the title the icon still there

Comment: i just remove new ActionBarDrawerToggle () ... and its gone :)

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following code to change the toolbar position.**

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```